# Disabling CSS for a table to prevent its clipping

Tags: css, html-table

Afaik, if you don't use any CSS, a `<table>` auto-resizes itself so that no text in it -- be it column data or headings -- gets clipped.

However in this [JS Bundlers Comparison](https://webpack.js.org/comparison/) table, that (as of Nov 16 2020) isn't displaying all its columns even in a fully maximized wide desktop screen window, even unchecking all of the table's styles in the *Styles* tab of *Chrome Developer Tools* results in no change whatsoever.

**Question**: What can I do in *Chrome Developer Tools* to get all the columns of the table to display without getting clipped, without even the horizontal or vertical scroll bars?

Comment: That table you're talking about in the webpack website has an `overflow-x: auto;` prop which enables the browser to display a scrollbar when content is exceeding the width. You can change that to `overflow-x: visible` AND its parent `.page` divs since it has its overflow prop set to `hidden`

Comment: `.page {overflow-x: hidden;}` is clipping the table. The `table` does not override the styling of any ancestral elements

Comment: @JonP That worked. Is there a good online resource that teaches these sort of things? Almost every tutorial teaches only basics. Just last week, I went through an 11+ hour long CSS course, and even then I couldn't figure this problem out! Please post your comment as a reply, so I can mark it as final.

Comment: @konekoya I only set  `.page`'s style to `visible` and it worked. Not sure, if I should mark JonP's or yours as final answer as I used `visible` from your comment AND tweaked ONLY .`page`'s style from JonP's.

Comment: You should accept Jon's answer as changing `.page`'s overflow prop should be enough which I did not think about.